# Eloquent Model for pivot table with 3 foreign keys?

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent

I am working on a project with has this kind of an model.

A vendor's table to store all vendor details - A vendor is like a company that offers some service.

**vendor**

```
id  | name
----+-------
 1  | abc 
 2  | def
```

Then I have a Services table which contains the list of all the services that a vendor can offer:

**service**

```
id | name
---+----------------
1  |  abc
2  |  def
3  |  ghi
```

And there is an area table which contains the list of all the areas from which vendor's can chose if they want to provide service in that area or not.

**Areas**

```
id | name
---+------
1  | abc
2  | def
3  | ghi
```

Now I want to have a pivot table that stores the details of which vendor provides which service in which area and at what price so my pivot table structure is like this:

```
vendor_id  | service_id | area_id | price 
-----------+------------+---------+---------
   1       |    1       |    2    |   25.00
   1       |    1       |    1    |   24.00
   2       |    1       |    1    |   23.00
```

and so on ...

So, now I have 3 different eloquent models for areas services and vendors; however, as the pivot table contains 3 foreign keys, I am unable to update the pivot table properly each time a vendor changes his preferences.

Can you please suggest me the way to define relationship in this scenario or should I change my table structure to store this data?

Comment: Instead of considering it as a pivot, consider it as an entity, you may call it provided services or whatever you want.
And create an eloquent model for it

Comment: I search a lot and found nothing in 2020. How did you attach & sync with 3 foreign keys? As i have to complete same scenario in database.

Answer (score 1):

The following article from 2013 did the job for me.

http://developed.be/2013/08/30/laravel-4-pivot-table-example-attach-and-detach/

The setup is something like below

```
Users
id | name | email

Projects
id | title | details

Roles
id | title

Project_User
id | project_id | user_id | role_id

class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('User','project_user','project_id','user_id')
            ->withPivot('role_id')
            ->join('roles','role_id','=','roles.id')
            ->select('roles.title as pivot_roles_title');
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you attach a new entry in here?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today.

You can use the `syncWithPivotValues()` method, passing the extra foreign key(s).

```
$vendor->services()->syncWithPivotValues($service_id, ['area_id' => $area->id])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Comment: I've got this error 

"Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::syncWithPivotValues(), 1 passed , at least 2 expected"